# Building a function to capture non-blank 'Int' from the User in Python

Tags: python, input, valueerror

I have a command line console game where I'm trying to capture integers from the User (the game is for learning times tables). I built a re-usable function to handle this which is working for blank answers, however will break if the User enters a string (e.g. "abc").

Can someone help me extend this function to filter out strings as well? (e.g. they should be asked to enter a number). I believe the error is being caused by the casting of int() in the return statement, however I need the input to be an Int for answer-checking comparison purposes (e.g. I compare their input to a stored answer, for which I need an *Int == Int* comparitor).

Function:

```
# gets a non-blank int from the User, printing a prompt and optionally displaying an error prompt
```

```
def get_int(prompt, err_prompt):
    input_int = ""

    # if entry is blank
    while not input_int:
        try:
            # enter input
            input_int = input(prompt)
            if not input_int:
                raise ValueError(err_prompt)

        except ValueError as err:
            print(err)
    return int(input_int)
```

Calling the function example:

```
# get a non-blank int from the User as a guess
# note 'current_q' is a string from a list, e.g. "2 x 2 = " which acts as the prompt
        guess = get_int(current_q, "You don't have a lot of other options. Try guessing a number...\n")
```

Example of the code working for blank answers:
[image]

Example of the code not working for strings:
[image]

Comment: Cast to int in the while loop and if it raises an exception ask them to try again.

Comment: I would just move the `int()` parsing to the `try` block.

Comment: you can use a `regular expression` to validate input, if it is valid go ahead, else `raise` an `error`.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement is wrong here:

```
if not input_int:
    raise ValueError(err_prompt)
```

It will not raise an error if the value is not an empty string since its 'truthy'.

Instead you need to manually convert the input to an int and catch error:

```
def get_int(prompt, err_prompt):
    input_int = ""

    # if entry is blank
    while not input_int:
        try:
            input_int = int(input(prompt))  # convert input to int
        except ValueError:
            print(err_prompt)   # if the value can't be converted simply print your existing error prompt
    return input_int
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `isdigit` on the `input` to check if it's an `int` before you cast it.

```
def get_int(prompt:str, error:str):
    while not (u:=input(prompt)).isdigit():
        print(error)
    return int(u)
```